# Custom Admin Routing - View/Admin/MyModel/index.ctp instead of View/MyModel/admin_index.ctp

Tags: cakephp, routes, admin, custom-routes, cakephp-2.2

In CakePHP, is there a way to set admin routing on an URL like this:

```
...com/admin/articles/
```

to go to:

```
View/Admin/Articles/index.ctp
```

instead of:

```
View/Articles/admin_index.ctp
```

My thought is, it would be nice to keep my admin files more separate from my front-end files, since I'd like to re-use my admin over many projects.  If this can be done, are their negative side-effects I haven't thought of?

Answer (score 1):

Just set Controller::$viewPath to whatever you need. In your AppController::beforeRender() set `$this->viewPath = 'Admin/' . $this->name;`

Comment: Won't that make it use `View/admin/Articles/admin_index.ctp` though?

Comment: Right it will, so change Controller::$view too.

Comment: Any chance you could explain in more detail in your answer?

Comment: $this->view = substr($this->action, 6);

Comment: Wouldn't that screw up non admin-driven pages?

Comment: Well obviously you will put that statement in an "if" block with a reasonable check for admin only actions.

Answer (score -1):

why don't you create a separate app for your admin? Or create a plugin with it? With that you could reuse it in all your projects.

Comment: This would work as a comment, but is not an answer to my question.